# How can I set "generic retpoline" as default because LFENCE does not serialize on my PC?

Tags: linux, cpu, 64-bit, spectre

I have Fedora 27 installed on my laptop with an older AMD CPU (AMD Turion X2 mobile processor RM-75 / 2.2 GHz). The following error message appears every time I boot:

Spectre V2: Spectre mitigation: LFENCE not serializing, switching to generic retpoline

Can I just set generic retpoline as default? Thanks!

Comment: have the same problem: could you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `spectre_v2=retpoline,generic` to the kernel boot command.